# Custom global components not applying style in NuxtJs

Tags: css, sass, nuxt.js

I have built some components such as buttons and I want to use and reuse just about everywhere in my site.

I have already create plugins

```js
Object.entries(components).forEach((([name, component]) => {
  Vue.component(name, component)
}))
```

and registered in nuxt.config

```js
plugins [
  '@/plugins/components'
]
```

```html
<style lang="scss">
  .btn__container {
    border-radius: '5px';
    border: '1px solid red';
    background-color: 'red';
  }
</style>
```

but then when i call the component it doesnt apply the style

```html
<v-button>button</v-button>
```

i am trying to inspect my custom button element and it got strikethrough i dunno why
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`border-radius: '5px';` is not valid CSS
Try with `border-radius: 5px;`!